# How can I add an attribute to a return value in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, attributes, c++-cli

In C#, you can decorate function return values with attributes, as follows:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
object LoadStuff();
```

My question is, how can I do this in C++/CLI? I have this:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::IUnknown)]
Object^ LoadStuff();
```

but the compiler is erroring with `'return' : unknown attribute qualifier`.

Is there an alternate syntax which I haven't been able to find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use returnvalue instead of return

```
[returnvalue: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::IUknown)]
```

The full list of attribute targets is available in section 28.2 of the C++/CLI spec [(PDF)](http://www.plumhall.com/C++-CLI%20draft%201.5.pdf)